# Use Kubernetes Ingress to have path routing with IP (no host/domainname) in GCP

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have no access to create a DNS/Domainname and therefore I am not able to fill the `host` field in my ingress' YAML file.

I simply want to use the IP like this:

`10.10.10.10/foo`

`10.10.10.10/bar`

This is my ingress' YAML file:

```
 apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
        name: foobar-ingress
        annotations:
            kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: foobar-trigger-static-ip
    spec:
        rules:
             http:
                  paths:
                      - path: /foo/*
                        backend:
                            serviceName: foo
                            servicePort: 80
                      - path: /bar/*
                        backend:
                            serviceName: bar
                            servicePort: 80
```

This is not valid as I try to push it with Helm. I was not able to find any information to that in https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/ since all the YAML examples are using a `host`. Is this even possible to do? Or is a host mandatory for that?

**EDIT**: I am using the GCP LoadBalancer

Comment: Could you provide more info regarding the helm chart that you have used? What exactly was it?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify nginx class in annotation to rewrite the incoming requests as below

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
        name: foobar-ingress
        annotations:
          kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: foobar-trigger-static-ip
          kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
          nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    spec:
        rules:
             http:
                  paths:
                      - path: /foo/?(.*)
                        backend:
                            serviceName: foo
                            servicePort: 80
                      - path: /bar/?(.*)
                        backend:
                            serviceName: bar
                            servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I do not use nginx ingress but GCP LoadBalancer

Comment: Loadbalancer(GCP) would not be able to give us access to both the foo and bar as loadbalancer will work on very specific set of pod
So I prefer to use https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx

Comment: unfortunately this is not an option since we use google cloud armor