# Egress trafic from k8s ckuster to multiple ip's with healthcheck

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have a service and an endpoint resources in Kubernetes. Pods send requests to Postgres through this service and EP. How can I change that approach so that requests would send to first ip, but not to the second one (though in case of unavailability of first ip, requests would send to the second), that is kinda failiver approach. I think it can be done with Ingress rule and Nginx Ingress-controller, but I didn't find how to send requests to ip addresses - not to a service (declaring in Ingress rule).

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgre-service
  namespace: test
spec:
  ports:
  - name: postgre
    port: 5432
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 5432
----------------
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: postgre-service
  namespace: test
subsets:
- addresses:
  - ip: first-ip
  - ip: second-ip
  - ip: third-ip
  ports:
  - name: postgre
    port: 5432
    protocol: TCP
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use Kubernetes Ingress to have path routing with IP (no host/domainname) in GCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59048650/use-kubernetes-ingress-to-have-path-routing-with-ip-no-host-domainname-in-gcp)

Comment: @IsmaelClementeAguirre nope, it doesn't, in that answer Ingress sends requests to services, I need send them to ip addresses